# Email alias with AAD and Intune

Tags: azure-active-directory, intune, microsoft365

I'm new to managing a small company using Intune and Azure Active Directory. I need to create an email alias (info@, webmaster@, etc) and have those emails go to a specific user. I created a group with the email alias I want to use but this appears to be more of a shared email box that has to be logged into.

Can someone help me or point me to the correct MS docs to accomplish this?

I've tried googling for the answer to this question but maybe I'm not using the correct search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add email alias in Microsoft 365 admin center.

Please refer to the detailed steps: [Add email aliases to a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/add-another-email-alias-for-a-user?view=o365-worldwide#add-email-aliases-to-a-user)。

Note the step 2:

> On the Active Users page, select the user > Manage email aliases.
>   **You won't see this option if the person doesn't have a license assigned to them.**

So you need to make sure the user has Exchange Online license.